# Semi-norm generating the standard locally convex topology on the space of locally finite Borel measures

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

In several articles available over the internet, it is written that:

> .. $M_{loc}(\Omega)$ is the space of locally finite Borel Measures on
>   $\Omega$ with the standard locally convex topology generated by
>   semi-norms $p_{\Phi}(\mu) = Var(\Phi_{\mu})$ where: $\Phi = \Phi (x)
>  \in C_{0}(\Omega)$ .

But, nowhere I am able to find the definition of this "Var." As it seems to me, it may be something like "Total Variation of a Measure" ; but I couldn't find the exact definition of the above "Var."

Can someone please give me the precise definition of "$Var (\Phi_{\mu})$" for the above case???

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing which makes sense to me is that $\Phi_\mu$is the finite measure given by $d\phi_\mu = \Phi \,d\mu$.

Then $Var(\Phi_\mu)$ is indeed the total variation of $\Phi_\mu$, which is the same as the norm of $\Phi_\mu$ as a linear functional on $C_b (\Omega)$, i.e.
$$
Var(\Phi_\mu) = \sup_{\|f\|\leq 1, f\in C(\Omega)} |\int f\Phi \,d\mu|.
$$